# Usurpation without "Usurpate"

Tags: morphology

It seems to me somehow odd to have **Usurpation** without having a corresponding ***Usurpate***. I know about back-formation, but in that case both words are present. Am I missing something? Are there more examples of the same situation? Is there a specific term for this?

The case mentioned above may be checked in AHD ([-ation](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Usurpation)/[-ate](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Usurpate)), Collins ([-ation](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/usurpation)/[-ate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/usurpate)), M-W ([-ation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usurpation)/[-ate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usurpate)), and Oxford Dictionaries ([-ation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/usurpation)/[-ate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/usurpate)).

Comment: The OED marks the verb *usurpate* obsolete. And yes, there are many such examples. For instance, *inflammation*, but not *inflammate*. I don't think this question is a good fit for ELL; it appears it's about etymology, more than learning English, and it might as well have been posted on ELU.

Comment: You do have the verb *usurp*, from which *usurpation* derives.

Comment: @Gustavson Webster (a little more comprehendible than the OED) says "Middle English, from Middle French, from Latin *usurpation-*, *usurpatio* act of using, from *usurpatus* (past participle of *usurpare* to use) + *-ion-*, *-io* -ion", so who knows. But I don't think that's what they're asking about.

Comment: It seems to me like it's just an example of a word where they threw in a few extra letters to make it flow. Given that the root verb is 'usurp', the simplest noun conjugation would be 'usurption.' Unfortunately, when spoken, there's an awkward stop between the *p* and the *t*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many verbs that don't end in *-ate* that have corresponding nouns in *-ation*: *converse, conversation; retard, retardation; expect, expectation; inform, information; observe, observation; consult, consultation; exult, exultation;  derive, derivation;  excite, excitation; provoke, provocation; administer, administration.*

The source of the English ending *-ation* is the Latin ending *-ātiō, -ātiōnis.* This was used to form nouns related to verbs of the first conjugation, which have a fourth principle part ending in *-āt-* (containing the first-conjugation theme vowel A).

English verbs taken from Latin are often based on the fourth principle part (giving us *-ate* verbs from Latin first-conjugation verbs), but not always. It depends on things like how old the verb is and whether it came through French. Latin-derived verbs that do not end in *-ate* usually have a stressed final syllable that either contains a long vowel or ends in a consonant cluster (but there are other less common forms for these verbs, like *administer* in the list above).

There are even a few *-ation* nouns that were formed in English by analogy to the ones taken from Latin. The Oxford English Dictionary entry for *-ation* mentions the examples *starvation* and *flirtation.*

Comment: Thank @sumelic. Would you please see the edited version of the question?

Answer (score 3):

This is called *morphological blocking* in linguistics. Basically, if there are two or more possible ways to form a word with a particular meaning (for example, by adding derivational affixes), then only one of these words will actually be used. And as a corollary, if two such words do exist, then there are likely to be different shades of meaning between then ("no absolute synonyms").

You will find plenty of examples in English due to its having  incorporated French Latinate words and morphology on top of the native words and morphology.

If you google the right jargon you'll find examples discussed in scholarly literature.

Comment: What do you mean by the _right jargon_? I did a quick search of _morphological blocking_ but failed to find some examples.

Comment: @Kaveh don't do a quick search.